# Not getting email-id of facebook after successful authentication in firebase db

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

Here, I am trying to login user by facebook, but after successful login I want to show user data to profile.class but I am not able to fetch email-id because of this. Moreover, in some solution I have seen various developers are using GraphRequest in handleFacebookToken(). Please help me that how to fetch email-id successfully as well as do I need to implement GraphRequest also? Please help

```
private void handleFacebookToken(AccessToken accessToken) {

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());

        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                    String name, email;
                    name = user.getDisplayName();
                    email = user.getEmail();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), profile.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    intent.putExtra("email", email);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please add the entire code that you are using for Facebook authentication. You are only sharing the part where authenticate with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Privacy Policy, Security reason of data, That's why you need to use graph API

Graph API returns only publicly available information. For details on User properties and permissions, see [Graph API Reference, User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user).

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        accessToken,
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(
                   JSONObject json_object,
                   GraphResponse response) {
                 try {
                        String email = json_object.getString("email");
                        String id = json_object.getString("id");
                        String name = json_object.getString("name");
                        Timber.d("facebook id%s", id);
                        presenter.facebookLogin(email, id, name, loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Can't we go by using facebook handleFacebookToken and get that? Means is using graph API is must? As I think fb has modified it's use. But by that I am not getting email-id